# how to change the default background image when info button is selected

Tags: xcode, button, background, default

Im running Xcode 4.3.2 I have built a basic iPad/iphone app.  On the main menu the info button is displayed. When I select it on my device the screen flips over and displays some info.  My question is, When the screen flips over, for a brief second, you can see an image in the background.  Although it's an image in my project folder I'm not quite sure how to change it or how it got there.  Thanks
-Anthony

Answer (score 0):

This image is actually the MainWindow_ipad.xib or MainWindow_iphone.xib file within my project. you can drag and drop a new image into it from your media library once you've put that image into your project folder and then selected xcode>file>add files to "your project's name"